# C# - SubSelect em Lambda e Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, expressões-lambda

Como montar a query abaixo em Lambda e/ou Linq?

```
select 
emp.cd_empresa AS ID,
emp.nm_razao_social + ' (' + emp.nm_fantasia + ')' AS EMPRESA,
(SELECT COUNT(con.cd_consulta) from tb_consulta_empresa con where con.cd_empresa = emp.cd_empresa and con.cd_consulta = 590) AS STATUSfrom tb_empresaemp order by 3 desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talvez desta forma?

```
var leftJoin = (from tbe in tb_Empresa
                join tce in tb_Consulta_Empresa on tbe.cd_empresa equals tce.cd_empresa into tbetce
                from tce in tbetce.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where tce.cd_consulta == 590
                select new
                {
                    ID = tbe.cd_empresa,
                    EMPRESA = $"{tbe.nm_razao_social} ({tbe.nm_fantasia})",
                    STATUS = tbetce.Count()
                });
```

É necessário, como é óbvio, ter atenção ao nome das tabelas e dos campos. O que coloquei na resposta são apenas sugestivos.

Comment: Obrigado! Exatamente isso.